# How to update php HTML Purifier with Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, htmlpurifier

I have an older version of HTML Purifer and I’m having difficulty finding information on how to upgrade the version to 4.14.

**Does anyone have any guide on how to do this?** I found some steps that was for newer users. So I conducted the following steps for new users but **will this work the same for users who is currently using HTML Purifier but is just trying to update the file?** The steps I found are as follows:

1. Updating the composer.json and adding **"ezyang/htmlpurifier":"4.11.0"** to the require property
2. Then running **composer ezyang/htmlpurifier --with-dependencies**

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually edit `composer.json`, you should then be able to simply run `composer update`. Alternatively, you you could run `composer require ezyang/htmlpurifier:4.11.0 --with-all-dependencies` to force an upgrade.

One or the other:

- Manually edit `composer.json` and run `composer update`.
- Simply run `composer require ezyang/htmlpurifier:4.11.0 --with-all-dependencies`.

There should be no need to do both.